# Is possible to reach 100% coverage of branches completed?

Tags: java, branch, junit4, assert

Prize is a variable type double (prize >=0.0) and in the Tests (jUnit) appears this message *1 of 4 branches missed*

I´ve written a condition which says **prize** has to be a positive number (including zero):

```
 assert (prize>= 0.0);
```

I´ve tried:

```
 @Test
 setPrize(2.2);
 assertEquals(c.getPrize(),2.2,0);


 @Test
 setPrize(0.0);
 assertEquals(c.getPrize(),0.0,0);


 @Test (expected = AssertionError.class)
 setPrize(-1.0);
 assertEquals(c.getPrize(),-1.0,0);
```

Function getPrize:

```
 public double getPrize() {
    return prize;
 }
```

Condition of getter:

```
    public Shop (String date, double prize){
    assert (date!= null);
    assert (date!= "");
    assert (prize>= 0.0);
    }
```

**How is possible to reach the total of branches completed?**

Thanks.

Comment: please share your getPrize method

Comment: @VinayPrajapati I have edited the question by adding the getter, I am using the EclEmma coverage tool

Comment: where is your condition in this setter? your question is incomplete. Please add minimum code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati hope that's what you wanted.

Comment: why are you having asserts inside a Constructor?